# Confused about calculation of steering force

Tags: physics, steering-behaviors

I'm reading *Programming Game AI by Example, by Mat Buckland*. What I don't understand there is why the individual behaviors return a vector representing change in velocity, but the combined result is treated as a force vector.

Here's the excerpt from the [update function](https://github.com/wangchen/Programming-Game-AI-by-Example-src/blob/master/Buckland_Chapter3-Steering%20Behaviors/Vehicle.cpp#L63):

```
  Vector2D SteeringForce = m_pSteering->Calculate();

  //Acceleration = Force/Mass
  Vector2D acceleration = SteeringForce / m_dMass;

  //update velocity
  m_vVelocity += acceleration * time_elapsed; 

  //make sure vehicle does not exceed maximum velocity
  m_vVelocity.Truncate(m_dMaxSpeed);

  //update the position
  m_vPos += m_vVelocity * time_elapsed;
```

And [`m_pSteering->Calculate()`](https://github.com/wangchen/Programming-Game-AI-by-Example-src/blob/master/Buckland_Chapter3-Steering%20Behaviors/SteeringBehaviors.cpp#L114) returns the weighted sum of different steering "forces", like `Seek`

```
Vector2D SteeringBehavior::Seek(Vector2D TargetPos)
{
  Vector2D DesiredVelocity = Vec2DNormalize(TargetPos - m_pVehicle->Pos())
                            * m_pVehicle->MaxSpeed();

  return (DesiredVelocity - m_pVehicle->Velocity());
}
```

So, how come steering functions like `Seek` just return change in velocity and don't take mass into account, but still get used as force?

Here's the source code

Comment: did you see [this tutorial](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-steering-behaviors-seek--gamedev-849).

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali I looked at the tutorial, it seems to be using the same formulas, but still doesn't explain the point I'm confused about.

Answer (score 1):

The guy who wrote the [original steering behaviors stuff](https://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/) was a little sloppy about accelerations versus forces. They differ, of course, only by a factor of the agent’s mass. In many multi-agent steering-behavior based systems mass is ignored, or set to one, which makes accelerations and forces equivalent. You tend to spend a lot of time tweaking with the strength and weighting of the steering forces, and how they get combined, so the units of mass (or non-unit values) can often be ignored. The more you care about the actual physics, the more you care about realistic values of mass, force, and acceleration.

Comment: One could additionally link to [Newton's laws of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton's_second_law).